# How to get event target default value JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to be able to get my target's default value. However, it returns `undefined`, even though it returns my edited text content.

Table

```
<table class="data  table-bordered table table-striped" id="ui" method="POST">
  <tr style="background-color:blue;color:white;">
    <td width="25%">Device-imei</td>
    <td>Device-Model</td>
    <td>device-nickname</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"111111"</td>
    <td>"Model"</td>
    <td>
      <div class="device-name" contenteditable>"Name"</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"11121341"</td>
    <td>"asdf"</td>
    <td>
      <div class="device-name" contenteditable>"Name"</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Javascript

```
$('.device-name').on('blur', function(event) {
  alert(event.target.defaultValue);
  alert(event.target.textContent);
});
```

EDIT
Found a way around my code
I added data value into my div and used the getAttribute to get my data
HTML

```
<table class="data  table-bordered table table-striped" id="ui" method="POST">
  <tr style="background-color:blue;color:white;">
    <td width="25%">Device-imei</td>
    <td>Device-Model</td>
    <td>device-nickname</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"111111"</td>
    <td>"Model"</td>
    <td>
      <div class="device-name" contenteditable data-value="Name">"Name"</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"11121341"</td>
    <td>"asdf"</td>
    <td>
      <div class="device-name" contenteditable data-value="Name">"Name"</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JavaScript

```
$('.device-name').on('blur', function(event){
    alert(event.target.getAttribute('data-value'));
alert(event.target.textContent);
})
```

Comment: `div` element doesn't have native `defaultValue` property. Also, it looks like you missed something, `method` is a property of `form` elements, when set for `table`, it hasn't any special meaning, it is just a custom attribute.

Comment: What do you mean by "default value"?

Comment: Event.target does not have "defaultValue", you will get content in  textContent. Here is the jsFiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Sagokharche/d50va6mf/

Comment: @Derek For example i change the value "Name" to "Dennis" I want to be able to retrieve both Name and Dennis

Comment: That’s not possible unless you store the content somewhere before doing any modifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The `target` property can be the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it. It is often useful to compare `event.target` to `this` in order to determine if the event is being handled due to event bubbling. This property is very useful in event delegation, when events bubble.

[source](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/)

So in your case it is the same as you would do

```
$('.device-name').on('blur', function(event) {
  alert(this.defaultValue);
  alert(this.textContent);
});
```

There is no such thing as `defaultValue`

**Solution**

If you want to store the value you can assign it to element attribute and retrive it using jQuery function `attr()` or `data()` or javascript function `getAttribute()`

```js
$('.device-name').on('blur', function(event) {
  alert(event.target.getAttribute('data-default'));
  alert($(event.target).attr('data-default'));
  alert($(event.target).data('default'));
  alert(event.target.textContent);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="data table-bordered table table-striped" id="ui" method="POST">
  <tr style="background-color:blue;color:white;">
    <td width="25%">Device-imei</td>
    <td>Device-Model</td>
    <td>device-nickname</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"111111"</td>
    <td>"Model"</td>
    <td>
      <div class="device-name" contenteditable data-default="Name">"Name"</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>"11121341"</td>
    <td>"asdf"</td>
    <td>
      <div class="device-name" contenteditable data-default="Name">"Name"</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```